# Is there a way to update static methods in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm running into a brick wall trying to update the file path of an image that I'm trying to display. The only way (so far that i see) is to pass the path as a sting using a static method but the image path its is stored and can be changed at a later time if you wanted to change it. Here is what i have so far

```
File  _bkimageFile = new File(look);


static var look = '/storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Images/IMG- 
20190320-WA0009.jpg';
```

If i try and pass in the value with a widget i get an error stating

```
Only static members can be accessed in 
initializers.dart(implicit_this_reference_in_initializer)
The type of 'look' can't be inferred because it refers to an instance 
method, '_read', which has an implicit type.
Add an explicit type for either 'look' or 
'_read'.dart(strong_mode_top_level_instance_method)
```

I know that static methods are build first during run time but im not sure as to what I'm doing wrong. Just in case you want to know the  "_read" is a widget and it looks something like this.

```
_read() async {
        final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        final key = 'foo';
        final value = prefs.getString(key) ?? 0;
        print('read: $value');
      }
```

I know the value is there because i use the widget on another screen and it returns values as it should.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by passing the value through a var into the

```
FileImage(new File(_bar)),


_bar(
////some code
return foo
)
```